# problem with convolution

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

I'm struggling with this kind of problem:

I have an assumption that $f$ and $g$  are in $L^2(R)$, and I should prove that $f\star g \rightarrow 0$ when $|x| \rightarrow \infty$. I think (but I'm not sure) I should use the theorem, that says $||f \star g||_\infty \le ||f||_2||g||_2$.

I would be thankful for any help with this problem! Thanks!

Comment: Assume $f * g$ does not converge to $0$ for $|x|\to \infty$ Can you find a contradiction to $||f*g||_\infty \leq ||f||_2||g||_2$?

Comment: I would have tried first to approximate $f$ and $g$ with compactly supported functions. In that case when $x$ is large enough the integrand of the convolution function is just zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's useful to use the Fourier transform. We have 
$$\mathcal{F}(f\star g)= \mathcal{F} f \cdot \mathcal{F} g$$

Apply to both sides the Fourier transform and get 
$$\mathcal{F}\mathcal{F} (f\star g) = \mathcal{F}(\mathcal{F} f \cdot \mathcal{F} g)$$

Now use that $\mathcal{F}\circ \mathcal{F}$ is a $\ne 0$ constant times the reflection in the argument 
$$\mathrm{const} \cdot f\star g (-x)$$
-- for the left hand side . For the right hand side use $\mathcal{F}f$, $\mathcal{F}g$ are also functions in $L^2$ so their product is in $L^1$ and the Fourier transform of a function in $L^1$ is a continuous function that converges to $0$ at infinity (Riemann-Legesgue). We conclude that $f\star g$ converges to $0$ for $|x| \to \infty$.